# java 1 program talking with another

Tags: java, load, classnotfoundexception

I am currently working on a plugin for a server. And in this plugin, it needs to call methods from a class in another folder. Here's an example:

```
public class LoadSkill{
private void load(String name, String type, CastingSkill cast){
    try{
        File folder = new File(this.plugin.getDataFolder(), "Skills");
        if(!folder.exists())folder.mkdirs();
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        if(files.length>0){
            for(File f : files){
                String skill = f.getName();
                skill = skill.substring(0, skill.length()-4);
                if(name.equals(skill)){
                    URL loadPath = f.toURI().toURL();
                    URL[] classUrl = new URL[]{loadPath};
                    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classUrl);
                    Class loadedClass = Class.forName("run.skill.Start", false, cl);
                    if(cast!=null)loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod(name, CastingSkill.class).invoke(loadedClass.newInstance(), cast);
                    else loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod(name).invoke(loadedClass.newInstance());
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error while trying to load skill " + name + "!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this would be a jar file inside the skills folder. NOTE: this is not runnable, thats why it doesn't have a main(String[] args) method. Also, this is the only class. Yes, the path does match as requested above.

```
public class Skill implements Castable{
    public void Enable(){System.out.println("Enabled")}
    public void Cast(){System.out.println("Casting")}
    public void StopAllTimers(){System.out.println("Stopped)}
    public void AddListener(){System.out.println("Listening")}
}
```

When I run this code however, I get a "ClassNotFoundException", and I'm not sure why. I've checking over this a few times and it seems everything is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace for your "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: Your class must have a main method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention several things:

1. Your Code will only work if your clas is located in the root package. If your class has a package name you will have to strip it from the url: file is c:\my\classes\java\lang\String.class then url has to be //file:/c:/my/classes.
2. Most servers work with kind of a classloader hirachy, to enable dynamically adding classes (almost as you try to). If your class depends from others, not included in the bootstrap classpath, you'll have to add appropiate parent classloader.
3. If your server is an javaEE server (no matter wether with ejb support or servlet runner only) and you do not work on the server itself, the ejb spec prohibits creation of own classloaders. This is because there is no way to get the right parent classloader in a portable fashion.
4. Most servers allow to configure additional pathes for classes on different levels of classloading hirarchy.

If you use some javaEE server you should specify which one in the question.